# Find turn values to undefined

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

My route here should show all the rooms, each room has 8 beds, I'm trying to 
check if all the beds are taken or not.

What's happening is that after the find in the function below the returned value is undefined

Here you can see the room route:

```
// Rooms Route
app.get('/rooms',function(req,res){
// ansArr = [];//arr for taken bed in room
var count, rNum, bNum;
var arrSortRooms = [], i=0;//arr to sort the boys and girls room
Hotelroom.find({},function(err, allRooms) {
    if(err){
        console.log('@@@@@@@@@@ Error @@@@@@@@');
        console.log(err);
        console.log('@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@');
    }
    else{
        // find how much beds open in room and put the answer in arrayy
        allRooms.forEach(function(room){ 
            getnum(room);
            arrSortRooms.push(room);
        });
        console.log('@@@@@@ Camp-Rendered @@@@@@');
        arrSortRooms = arrSortRooms.sort(function(a, b){return b.room_num 
        a.room_num });
        res.render('rooms.ejs',{arrSortRooms:arrSortRooms,ansArr:ansArr});

    }
});
});
```

and here is the function that counts the taken beds in each room

```
function getnum(room){
    count=0;
    BedInRoom.find({room_num:room.room_num},function(err,rm){
        if(err){

        }
        else{
            rm.forEach(function(r){
                count++;
                return count;
            });
        }
    });
}
```

I appreciate your help.

Comment: problem solved:

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved.

the room route:

```
//Rooms Route
app.get('/rooms',function(req,res){
var count, rNum, bNum;
var arrSortRooms = [], i=0,c; //arr to sort the boys and girls 
room
var ansArr = [];//arr that contain how much beds are taken in 
//every room
BedInRoom.find({},function(err,allbeds){
 if(err){
     console.log(err);
 }
 else{
     Hotelroom.find({},function(err, allRooms) {
         if(err){
            console.log('@@@@@@@@@@ Error @@@@@@@@');
            console.log(err);
            console.log('@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@');
         }
         else{
            //find how much beds taken in every room
            allRooms.forEach(function(room){
                c=setCount(allbeds,room)
                ansArr.push(c);
                arrSortRooms.push(room);
            });
            console.log('@@@@@@ Rooms-Rendered @@@@@@');
            arrSortRooms = arrSortRooms.sort(function(a, b) 
            {return b.room_num - a.room_num });
            res.render('rooms.ejs', 
            {arrSortRooms:arrSortRooms,ansArr:ansArr});
             }
         });
      }
    });
});
```

the function:

```
/////// function //////////////////////////////////////////

function setCount(allbeds,room){//count taken beds per room
count =0;
allbeds.forEach(function(b){
    if(b.room_num==room.room_num)
    {
        count++
    }
});
return room.room_num+","+count;
//return the room and the taken beds
}
```